# Ubuntu for Mechanical Engineering

Tags: 12.04

I'm studying Mechanical Engineering (3rd year) and i'm new to ubuntu. How can make the best use of it in my field?
Is it helpful in anyway for mechanical engineers better than windows? If so, how?
and Suggest me ideas please.

Answer (score 3):

[Bricscad (Comercial, Autocad Clone)](http://www.bricsys.com/en_INTL/bricscad/)

[Varicad (3D based CAD software available for Linux)](http://www.varicad.com/en/home/)

[Draftsight (free, Autocad Clone, but no Autolisp)](http://www.3ds.com/products/draftsight/overview/)

[Ares Commander](http://www.graebert.com/)

Freecad  (in the repo)

QCAD (repo)

[Medusa4](http://www.cad-schroer.com/Software/MEDUSA4) (free personal version, very good commercial software)

Matlab & SPSS has linux version (if need those)

for more 
[CAD & Linux: The LUnIx Linux CAD Links](http://www.tech-edv.co.at/05_LUnIx/80_CAD~2f3d/10_CAD~20Links/index.php)

[Mechanical Engineering Useful Software in Linux](http://linuxmadeasy.blogspot.com/2011/09/so-as-usual-ive-no-wrote-in-this-space.html)

Comment: While this could answer the question, it's better if you put the information  and link to the source.

Answer (score 1):

For mechanical engineering, you'll probably need advanced CAD. Most CAD programs are exclusive to Windows. Although there are programs like QCAD, FreeCAD, and LibreCAD for Linux, they don't make it nearly worth it to use Ubuntu for engineering because they aren't nearly up to the same standard.